# Node render engine project directory path '{website-path}\app' does not exist

Tags: jss

We reently moved Sitecore First from CodeFirst. Which means we have deployed jss app to the Sitecore. But when we try to open Exprience Editor, we face below issue:

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Node render engine project directory path '{website-path}\app' does not exist. Ensure your JavaScript code has been deployed and that the configured path is correct.
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngineFactory.CreateNodeServicesOptions(RenderEngineOptions engineOptions, NodeRenderEngineOptions nodeRenderEngineOptions)
   at DTCM.Feature.LayoutServiceExtensions.PatchedNodeRenderEngineFactory.CreateNodeServices(RenderEngineOptions options, NodeRenderEngineOptions nodeRenderEngineOptions) in D:\Data\Inetpub\DT\VD\src\server\DTCM.Feature.LayoutServiceExtensions\PatchedNodeRenderEngineFactory.cs:line 145
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.GenericConcurrentPool`1.Pop()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.GenericConcurrentPool`1.CheckOut()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

Any clue as to what's missing in here?

Answer (score 1):

When you open Experience Editor or try to open the page, Sitecore tries to find a jss app with the same name as a context site. As far as I see, the site has the "app" name. I suppose your JSS app has different name. You need to synchronize your jss app and site names.

Comment: hello, I have the same issue and I checked the app name and site name, they are the same in config file,
is there any other reason for this error??